# Negative registers in arm assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture

Hey guys I'm learning the arm assembly language from the book by Alan Clements.
In one of the practice problems there is a question asking for the effective address given generated by the instruction `LDR r0,[r2,‐r3, LSL #1]`?

I'm thrown off by the `-r3`, does this signify the negative of whatever value is stored in `r3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus sign (`-`) means that the index register R3 is subtracted from the base register R2 after being shifted. In other words, the effective address is `r2 - (r3 LSL 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So -r3, LSL #1 just means a negative offset by [r3] multiplied by 2? i.e if r2 = n and r3 = #4 then after `[r2,‐r3, LSL #1]` r2 would be n-8?

Comment: @Deik It ends up being the same value because it's a left shift, but that's not what it means.  It means it's multiplied by 2 and then subtracted.

Comment: ok sorry so let's consider `LDR r0, [r2,‐r3, LSL #1]!` if r2 = n and r3 = #4 then the updated r2 would be n-8?

Comment: @Deik Does it update `r2`? Doesn't it just load `r0`? I'm not sure if ARM has those post/prefix pointer adjustments, but on most of the CPUs similar instruction does use register values to calculate target memory address without affecting the values in registers (there are some exceptions having `+` and `-` post/pre operators to actually modify also the address registers, I can recall GameBoy modified Z80 as one, but I forgot which other major CPU had it... ARM or M68k? ... but then the `-` doesn't mean subtraction, but pre-decrement) ... Anyway @OP: go to debugger, single-step, check result.